# `TemplateDoesNotExist` error though it does exist

Tags: django

I wrote password reset and change templates structured as

```
    In [10]: !tree /Users/me/desktop/Django/forum/user/templates/user
    /Users/me/desktop/Django/forum/user/templates/user
    ├── activate.html
    ├── failure.html
    ├── logged_out.html
    ├── login.html
    ├── password_change_done.html
    ├── password_change_form.html
    ├── password_reset_complete.html
    ├── password_reset_confirm.html
    ├── password_reset_done.html
    ├── password_reset_email.html
    ├── password_reset_form.html
    ├── password_reset_subject.txt
    ├── register.html
    ├── success.html
    └── validate.html
```

It throws `TemplateDoesNotExist` error when I test it in browser
http://127.0.0.1:8001/user/password_reset/

```
    TemplateDoesNotExist at /user/password_reset/
    /user/password_reset_form.html
    Request Method: GET
    Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8001/user/password_reset/
    Django Version: 1.11.13
    Exception Type: TemplateDoesNotExist
    Exception Value:    
    /user/password_reset_form.html
```

all the passwords_*_* did not perform as intended but others function finely.

[image]

The urls.py

```
#Costomize the authentication system
urlpatterns = [
    # show the register page
    url(r"^register/$", views.register, name="register"),
    ...
    url(r'^password_reset/$', auth_views.PasswordResetView.as_view(template_name="/user/password_reset_form.html"), name='password_reset'),
        ]
```

What's the problem with my multiple password templates?

Comment: There is nothing wrong with that, but paths that start with a slash are **absolute** paths. So that means they start at the *root* of your filesystem.

Comment: ty, I got it @WillemVanOnsem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your template name should be `user/password_reset_form.html`.

check [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/class-based-views/base/#templateview)